# UITableView - Only show full cell after scroll stops

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

What I'd like to do is display only the full cell when scroll completes. In other words, if the user scrolls and there is a partial cell being displayed, automatically move the contents so the partial cell is fully visible.

The reason is that each cell will have content based on which visible cell it's in.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the visible cells when scrolling completes by overriding DecelerationEnded in your UITableViewDelegate subclass:

```
public override void DecelerationEnded (UIScrollView scrollView)
{
    UITableViewCell[] visibleCells = tableVC.TableView.VisibleCells;

    ...
}
```